# Moving PayPal Payment iFrame to Checkout page

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

**The Problem**

Hi, I'm trying to move the payment iframe from its own page to the main checkout page so that I just have a one page form for checkout. I [followed the directions here](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/express-checkout-drupal-commerce) but wasn't able to get it to work (ie. I moved the 'review' section to 'disabled' and move the 'payment' section to 'checkout' in configuration).

**The Current Status of My Situation**

I'm using the Drupal Payflow Link module, and I have all my items in my checkout pane in store configuration. However, when a user goes to the checkout page they fill out all their information and also choose what payment method they want to use, but the actual entering of the payment information (credit card for example) still happens on the 'next' page. I want everything on ONE page.

**Question**

Anyone know how to make this happen with PayPal Advanced Payments/PayFlow Link so that entering the credit card details also appears on the main checkout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually just isn't possible. The iframe depends on having a completed order object, which you can't possibly have (or know for certain) if it's on the same page as fields placed to collect user input to complete that order. The same is true for all redirect, tokenized, or iframe based payment solutions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I guess you can't do ANYTHING you want with the code in Drupal after all.

Comment: hehehe, yeah, some things are quiet a challenge. The only *potential* way for something like this to work would be to use Ajax to update the order object in the background and refresh the iframe once you were assured the order wouldn't be changing any more. But my guess is that'd be more fragile than it's worth.